# How do i disable and enable dropdownlist item based on a user selection on another dropdownlist

Tags: sapui5

I have layout row which contains a dropdown, textfield and two buttons to add and remove rows.
My requirement is i have 10 items in dropdownlist if select one item (say Item1) and click on add row button, a new row will be created as same as first row. Now in the second row dropdownlist items i want to disable the selected item of previous dropdownlist item (Item1).

And i if change the dropdown item of first row to Item3 then automatically in the second row dropdown item it(Item1) should be enabled and vice versa.

How can i do this.

Please help me on this.

Thanks
Sathish

Answer (score 3):

There are probably more ways to do it, but I would store the selected items in an array and store that in your client model.

Then bind the `enabled` property of your dropdown template to a formatter function which returns `false` or `true`, depending on whether the template item is in the selected array or not

Comment: Well, unless your boss is willing to pay me for it, I'm not going to write any working code if you don't mind ;-) But to give some hints, you should use **databinding** and a formatter function (which reads the selected items from your model) to set the `enabled` property of the `ListItems`, and not in a loop... To add the array with selected items, simply add a new property `foo` in your JSON model and set the array using <yourModel>.setProperty("/foo", arrBar)

Comment: haha ...... Thanq Qualiture.  I think i have done some 60% in it. Anyway thanks for ur contribution.... ;-)